# Add custom claims to identity when using Windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I am having a difficult time understanding how to add custom claims when using Windows authentication in a .Net MVC app.

The challenge here is to populate the users's identity with custom claims from the database on login, so as to avoid making a db call every time I want to check a custom authorization attribute. But the use of Windows auth complicates things for me, as there's no login method in which to put the code that populates the roles.

Is there a method to override, or some other way to hook into the Windows auth login process?

Comment: if using mvc then after authentication take the current principal get the values from db and add the custom claims to it.

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, I'm not sure at what point in the process to add those custom claims? What's the login event that provides the opportunity to do that?

Answer (score 7):

In **.NET Core 2.0** you should use IClaimsTransformation.

For example:

```
public class CustomClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity)
          .AddClaim(new Claim(claim.Name, claim.Value)); //your values

        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

And add this code to Startup.cs

```
...
services.AddMvc();

services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation,CustomClaimsTransformer>(); // Add this
```

I don't know how to do this in ASP.NET MVC :/.

This is my first answer here :).

Answer (score 0):

For .NET Framework, using windows authentication, you can add claim in Application_PostAuthenticateRequest.

Here is the sample code

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var birthDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
        var identity = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First();
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, birthDate.ToString()));
    }
}
```