# ASP.NET Core Custom Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this kind of custom authorization configuration. The problem is that I want to check for submodule and if it has rights. I have a also a login controller where I'm building claims and etc, and adding them.  But I think I'm missing something here also. I should Add claims to current prinicipal I guess but I don't know how:

Here is my login action in login controller

```cs
[HttpGet("login")]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        var userName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.GetUserNameFromHttpContext();
        var user = _userClient.GetUserByUserName(userName);
        var loggedIUserDto = new LoggedInUserDto {UserName = userName};
        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        if (user == null)
        {
            return Unauthorized($"User {userName} does not exits in DB"); 
        }

        var userModulesWithSubmodules = _loginClient.GetUserModulesWithSubmodules(userName);
        loggedIUserDto.UserModulesWithSubmodules = userModulesWithSubmodules;

        if (userModulesWithSubmodules.Count == 0)
        {
            return Conflict($"User {userName} has no modules"); 
        }

        foreach (var module in userModulesWithSubmodules)
        {
            foreach (var submodule in module.Submodules)
            {
                var submoduleActionList = new List<string>();
                if (submodule.CanAdd)
                {
                    submoduleActionList.Add("CanAdd");
                }

                if (submodule.CanEdit)
                {
                    submoduleActionList.Add("CanEdit");
                }

                if (submodule.CanRead)
                {
                    submoduleActionList.Add("CanRead");
                }

                if (submodule.CanDelete)
                {
                    submoduleActionList.Add("CanDelete");
                }

                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
                claims.Add(new Claim(submodule.SubmoduleName, string.Join(',', submoduleActionList)));
            }

        }

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;

        return Ok(loggedIUserDto);
    }
```

CustomeAuthorize

```cs
    public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
   {
    private SubmoduleActionType _submoduleActionType;
    private SubmoduleType _submoduleType;

    public SubmoduleActionType ActionType;

    public SubmoduleType Type {
        get => _submoduleType;
        set
        {
            _submoduleType = value;
            Policy = $"{_submoduleType.ToString()};{_submoduleActionType.ToString()}";
        }
    }

    public CustomAuthorize(SubmoduleActionType submoduleActionType, SubmoduleType submoduleType)
    {
        _submoduleActionType = submoduleActionType;
        _submoduleType = submoduleType;
    }
}
```

Below is my requirement class :

```cs
    public class SubmoduleTypeRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public SubmoduleActionType? ActionType { get; set; }

    public SubmoduleType? Type { get; set; }

    public SubmoduleTypeRequirement(SubmoduleActionType actionType, SubmoduleType type)
    {
        Type = type;
        ActionType = actionType;
    }
}
```

Here is my Handler class

```cs
  public class SubmoduleAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SubmoduleTypeRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SubmoduleTypeRequirement submoduleRequirement)
    {
        if (!submoduleRequirement.ActionType.HasValue)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No action type provided");
        }

        if (!submoduleRequirement.Type.HasValue)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No submodule type provided");
        }

        if (!context.User.HasClaim(uc => uc.Type == submoduleRequirement.Type.ToString()))
        {
            context.Fail();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        var grantedRights = Convert.ToString(context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == submoduleRequirement.Type.ToString()));

        if (grantedRights.Contains(submoduleRequirement.ActionType.ToString()))
        {
            context.Succeed(submoduleRequirement);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

And finally a policy class:

```cs
public class SubmodulePolicy : IAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{
    public SubmodulePolicy(IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options)
    {
        DefaultPolicyProvider = new DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider(options);
    }

    public DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider DefaultPolicyProvider { get; }  

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        var submoduleTypeAndAction = policyName.Split(";");
        var submoduleTypeString = submoduleTypeAndAction[0];
        var actionTypeString = submoduleTypeAndAction[1];

        var submoduleTypeParsed = System.Enum.TryParse(submoduleTypeString, out SubmoduleType submoduleType);
        var actionTypeParsed = System.Enum.TryParse(actionTypeString, out SubmoduleActionType submoduleActionType);

        if (actionTypeParsed && submoduleTypeParsed)
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
            policy.AddRequirements(new SubmoduleTypeRequirement(submoduleActionType, submoduleType));
            return Task.FromResult(policy.Build());
        }

        if (!actionTypeParsed || !submoduleTypeParsed)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot parse action or submoduleType from Policy");
        }

        return DefaultPolicyProvider.GetPolicyAsync(policyName);
    }

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetDefaultPolicyAsync()
    {
        return DefaultPolicyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync();
    }
}
```

The problem is my code never get's reached to my GetPolicy. It always goes to GetDefaultPolicyAsync method. Not even the attribute does not get fired. Should I have to regiter the Custom Attribute somewhere? I doubt that. Whatever I find on the internet, even in the official docs is always with one argument, but I need two of them.

Oh and here is my configuration in startup class

```cs
        services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, SubmodulePolicy>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, SubmoduleAuthorizationHandler>();
     services.AddAuthorization();
```

Any idea what's wrong? Is there any restriction for only one argument? Also I'm thinking about replacing that with a filter.

EDIT:

As requested my startup class. Just to comment - the jwt configuration is disabled as I had a problem with getting a json file with constants (I was prompted for user name and password when getting the file - iis server). This web api is combined with angular 2+ (v7)

My startup class:

```cs
   public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());

        services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, SubmodulePolicy>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, SubmoduleAuthorizationHandler>();

        //var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("Settings");
        //services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);
        //var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        //var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);

        //services
        //    .AddAuthentication(auth =>
        //    {
        //        auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        //        auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        //    })
        //    .AddJwtBearer(jwtBearer =>
        //    {
        //        jwtBearer.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        //        jwtBearer.SaveToken = true;
        //        jwtBearer.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        //        {
        //            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        //            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        //            ValidateIssuer = false,
        //            ValidateAudience = false
        //        };
        //    });

        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        });

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        var container = new ContainerBuilder();

        container.RegisterType<PermissionsClient>()
            .As<IPermissionsClient>()
            .WithParameter("baseServiceUrl", Configuration.GetSection("Settings")["BaseApiUrl"])
            .WithParameter("clientCertThumbprint", Configuration.GetSection("Settings")["BaseApiClientThumbPrint"])
            .SingleInstance();

        container.RegisterType<LoginClient>()
            .As<ILoginClient>()
            .WithParameter("baseServiceUrl", Configuration.GetSection("Settings")["BaseApiUrl"])
            .WithParameter("clientCertThumbprint", Configuration.GetSection("Settings")["BaseApiClientThumbPrint"])
            .SingleInstance();

        container.RegisterType<UserClient>()
            .As<IUserClient>()
            .WithParameter("baseServiceUrl", Configuration.GetSection("Settings")["BaseApiUrl"])
            .WithParameter("clientCertThumbprint", Configuration.GetSection("Settings")["BaseApiClientThumbPrint"])
            .SingleInstance();

        container.RegisterType<SenderClient>()
            .As<ISenderClient>()
            .WithParameter("baseServiceUrl", Configuration.GetSection("Settings")["BaseApiUrl"])
            .WithParameter("clientCertThumbprint", Configuration.GetSection("Settings")["BaseApiClientThumbPrint"])
            .SingleInstance();

        container.Populate(services);
        ApplicationContainer = container.Build();

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your startup.cs?  What authentication do you have set up there?  Cookies?  JWT?

Comment: I''ve edited my question, and added the startup class

Comment: If you don't have authentication working, authorization won't work.  How can I tell what you are allowed to do when I can't tell who you are?

Comment: But I have something like that services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); this is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working. The problem Was in the attribute that I've created. This is strange beacuse documentation which is here https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Anyway the parrt, where policy name is set in the setter of the property seems to now work for me. I don't know why. After I discovered (although this is obvious when you inherit something) that besides my custom paramteters I can pass also a Policy name I've tried to test it once more. And when I've hardcoded the policy name to my custom attribute suddenly the break point in GetPolicyAsync method got hit. So I've tried something like that

```cs
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
  private const string _policyName = "SubmodulePolicy"
  private SubmoduleActionType _submoduleActionType;
  private SubmoduleType _submoduleType;

  public SubmoduleActionType ActionType;

  public SubmoduleType Type { get; set;}

  public CustomAuthorize(SubmoduleActionType submoduleActionType, SubmoduleType submoduleType)
  {
    _submoduleActionType = submoduleActionType;
    _submoduleType = submoduleType;
    Policy = $"{_policyName}-{submoduleActionType.ToString()}-{submoduleType.ToString()}"
}
}
```

And suddenly it start to work. Another thing is that in the login controller you can add claims to the user but if this is windows authentication here

```cs
public class SubmoduleAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SubmoduleTypeRequirement>
 {
     protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SubmoduleTypeRequirement submoduleRequirement)
{
    if (!submoduleRequirement.ActionType.HasValue)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("No action type provided");
    }

    if (!submoduleRequirement.Type.HasValue)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("No submodule type provided");
    }

    if (!context.User.HasClaim(uc => uc.Type == submoduleRequirement.Type.ToString()))
    {
        context.Fail();
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

      var grantedRights = Convert.ToString(context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == submoduleRequirement.Type.ToString()));

     if (grantedRights.Contains(submoduleRequirement.ActionType.ToString()))
      {
        context.Succeed(submoduleRequirement);
      }

      return Task.FromResult(0);
  }
 }
```

In the http context you will get different context then I'm updating in the login method. So I had to use this [Add custom claims to identity when using Windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48434667/add-custom-claims-to-identity-when-using-windows-authentication) and populate claims in here instead of the login method. The last one maybe obvious for many, but It wasn't for me. Maybe also my let's say adventure will help someone.